# shell script string replace in huge file

Tags: php, shell

I need to parse a huge page ... with some strings like this:

```
<li class="specialclass"><a href="http://some.changingurl.com" ..(some changing classes)..>
```

I need to change the above to:

```
<li class="specialclass">http://some.changingurl.com<a href="http://some.changingurl.com" ..(some changing classes)..>
```

Then later on I can remove all html tags but keep the url saved. Only the url is changing.

Please help me write a subsititution.

Thank you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: actually i am stuck and don't know where to start. ty

Comment: you can use the shell command 'sed' in linux.  Have it do a regex find and replace to modify the file to your liking

Comment: yea. i am not good with sed and stuff, especially with regex.

Comment: This has been asked many times here on S.O. You need to spend a little time to research the options. You'll find that `sed` is a fragile solution. Perl will probably work OK, but you'll have to spend some time to master the regular expressions. OR look for questions with xmlstarlet, as this tool is designed to fix xml as you describe (assuming it is well-formed) (clean html can be converted to xhtml, and then you can use xmlstarlet). No easy answers. Sorry and good luck.

Comment: there is always an easy solution! don't think you know everything, never. sed -r 's/<a href="([^["]*)"/\1&/' input-file >new-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/<a href="([^["]*)"/\1&/' input-file >new-file
```

this oneliner does the trick.

Comment: You might need a /g modifier since there could be multiple hrefs in a single line.  But...why is there a "[" after the "^"?  Also, while it wasn't specifically asked for in the question, <a href='url'> also works with most browsers so you might need to handle ' as well as ".